# Javascript variable is undefined error

Tags: javascript

I'm getting this error :

> TypeError : object is undefined.

In same time the id of my object is printed.
[image]

Here's my code :

```
var tempArray = [];
var  getCategoriesArray = function (id) {
  var object = getObject(id);
  console.log("id : " + object.id);  // the id is printed correctly 
  tempArray[tempArray.length] = object;
  if (object.has("parent") == false) {
    console.log(tempArray);
    return tempArray;
  }
  return getCategoriesArray(object.get("parent"));
};

var getObject = function (id) {

  for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    var object = response[i];

    if (object.id == id) {
      console.log( "name : " + object.get("name")); // the name is printed
      return object;
    }
  }
}

$('#category').on("select2:select", function (e) {
  tempArray = []; 
  getCategoriesArray($(this).val());
});
```

Please what I've missed in my code ?

**Update**
I've figured the issue instead of this :

> return getCategoriesArray(object.get("parent"));

I've to use this

> return getCategoriesArray(object.get("parent").id);

because my function should have an `id` as parameter not an `object`

Comment: if `object` has no `id`, it returns with `false`. This happens, so there will be no `object`.

Comment: Maybe response variable is not available in get object function?

Comment: I'm sure that my array will contain the searched `id` and also the parent of that object because I got all objects in same array.

Comment: `console.log(object)` – What does that give you?!

Comment: @deceze print this `object : [object Object] and object : undefined` after that I get the error.
Also for those who voted down why !?

Comment: First debug you `getObject()`..in that do you get `object.id` otherwise it won't return anything..

Comment: @Chlebta Please read about composing [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Examples](http://sscce.org/). There is a lot of noise in your question.

Comment: @deceze thank you, your answer helped me to find the issue.

Comment: And that's why you've received downvotes, because this is trivial debugging you shouldn't have to ask Stack Overflow for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hy,

In function **getObject**, if there is no id matching, you don't return an valid object.

You must verify in **getCategoriesArray** if the returned object from **getObject** is  not false.

```
var  getCategoriesArray = function (id) {
   var object = getObject(id);
   if (!object) //do some work
   else {
     // do your work
     console.log("id : " + object.id);
   }
}
```